# IIS 7 and ASP MVC issue with period in query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an issue where I am sending over an email address to be validated against (make sure its not already used and is a valid email address). Now it worked fine on Cassini, but now I am using IIS7 it refuses to map the route.

The Url would look like:

http://localhost:23456/is/email/taken/test%40test.com

I have turned the route debugger on to make sure there is no problem with the route, and if I remove the ".com" bit at the end it works fine and the route matches (although its not a valid email address so is invalid). However if I leave the .com or whatever .extension is used, the route debugger doesnt even display so it makes me think IIS isnt even directing the traffic to ASP and is looking for a static file.

Has anyone else had this before? and if so how do you solve it?

Comment: I am using IIS Express and it seems to work fine. Have you tried in IIS Express as well?

Comment: I dont get an error just a blank page, checked for IIS logs but couldnt find them. Not tried IIS Express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, IIS may be treating that as a file with an extension that is blocked or mapped to a handler that is not MVC.  It first checks to see if there is a physical file on disk so some of the handling of the URL isn't all MVC engine only.  Do you have configurations that are protecting/refusing some extensions?

Comment: I have not setup any custom settings on IIS, it is as default, the web.config for this project does however load a custom module which deals with CORS based requests, but even so, all it does is just pass back some additional headers.